# How to calculate the Zoom Level for Google Maps based on size of Map and and Distance in Meters in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-maps-markers, distance

I have a `Google Map` Widget in a Circle. The user location is always in the center. On the map there is a marker which the user should see right at the edge of the map but completely visible.

**These are my variables:**

```
LatLng userPosition = LatLng(37.799165198213664, -122.44392812532321);
LatLng markerPosition = LatLng(37.80201081904288, -122.41954944718842);
double defaultZoomLevel = 17.0;
double distanceToMarkerInMeters = 2165.0;
double mapWidth = 400.0;
```

**My Question would be**

How does a function look like which calculates the needed `zoomLevel` to view the marker just on the edge of the map?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate a function which works in my case. However I can not assure you that it will work exactly the same because I had to play with the `zoomConstant` ans `zoomExponent` variables.

Here is the code, I hope it helps someone:

```
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    setState(() {
      _controller = controller;

      getDistanceToMarker(target: markerPosition);

      double newZoomLevel = _calculateZoomLevel(distanceToMarker);

      _controller
          .moveCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(userPosition, newZoomLevel));
    });
  }

  void getDistanceToMarker({required LatLng target}) async {
    LatLng latLng = LatLng(target.latitude, target.longitude);
    double targetLat = latLng.latitude;
    double targetLng = latLng.longitude;
    double userLat = userPosition.latitude;
    double userLng = userPosition.longitude;

    var p = 0.017453292519943295;
    var a = 0.5 -
        cos((targetLat - userLat) * p) / 2 +
        cos(userLat * p) *
            cos(targetLat * p) *
            (1 - cos((targetLng - userLng) * p)) /
            2;

    setState(() {
      distanceToMarker = ((12742 * asin(sqrt(a))) * 1000);
    });
  }

  double _calculateZoomLevel(double distance) {
    const double zoomConstant = 125.0; //ChatGPT made it 1000.0
    const double zoomExponent = 1.0; //ChatGPT made it 2.0

    double newZoomLevel =
        zoomLevel - (log(distance / zoomConstant) / log(2.0)) * zoomExponent;

    return newZoomLevel;
  }
```